What are .vsidx files for in a C# console project in Visual Studio 2022?
I am generating file trees in my projects, I am simply curious about this type of file, because I cannot find a complete answer on the Internet. But it is not a problem in my learning C# fundamentals course that I am finishing.
I was searching on a page about file types (fileinfo.com), but I couldn't find any information about .vsidx files. I only need the information about this file type to properly document my file trees.

It's internal metadata used by VS, it's located under the .vs directory in your solution; you can safely ignore it (and it shouldn't be checked-in to source-control).

This question is similar to: What is vsidx in Visual Studio and why is it autogenerated?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
